# How to view container stdout log message

Tags: kubernetes

I my nginx container access log linked to stdout. when I use `kubect logs` command not its not listing the access log information.

What is the right way to look at access logs?

```
ls -ltr /var/log/nginx/access.log
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            11 Dec 24 23:41 /var/log/nginx/access.log -> /dev/stdout
```

Thanks
SR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe is [a problem related with Docker](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/19616). You can find [more information here](https://github.com/hashicorp/vault/issues/2936), but basically, it seems that you have to symlink to `/proc/1/fd/1`, instead of just `/dev/stdout`. But this will only work if the nginx process is the pid 1 inside the container. [This comment has the more information](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/19616#issuecomment-174355979).